# Как отделить класс в структуре productFlavors?

Tags: android, build, settings

`ProductFlavors` состоит из 10 организаций.
Есть `class MainActivity`, содержимое которого уникально для 9 из 10 организаций.
Как сделать, чтобы не копировать `MainActivity` 9 раз для каждой орг-й и в дальнейшем не редактировать каждый из них?

Comment: То есть у вас 10 разных видов главных окон в одном приложении? Или сама структура главного окна одна и та же (те же кнопки, списки их местоположение и так далее), а меняется только содержимое?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin MainActivity для примера я указал, есть несколько таких классов, у которых вся структура  и т.д одинаковые для 9 орг-й